# JQuery disable 16 years date from selected date - jquery-ui-datepicker

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

How to disable the 16 years date(Date-2) range from selected date(Date-1)

**Example:**

Selected Date from date-1: 26-09-2016

Disabled Date from date-2: 26-09-2016 - 25-09-2000

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( ".datepicker1" ).datepicker( { dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', minDate: 0 } );           
    //$( ".datepicker2" ).datepicker( { dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', minDate: new Date(2015, 0, 1), maxDate: new Date(2015, 5, 31) } );

  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date-1 <input type="text" id="datepicker1" class="datepicker1"></p>

<p>Date-2 <input type="text" id="datepicker2" class="datepicker2"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Please update the answer!
Thanks to every one.

Comment: So you are trying to disable a range of dates within your datepicker?

Comment: Yes, Disable date range before 16 years from selected date.

Comment: why not just create a date object and then subtract 16 years.  Then use that as the min date?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" );
```

Here do you have the JQuery datepicker widget example's
[Jquery datapicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate)

otherwise, i miss understand your question.

Comment: Please see my question **Example:**  for understand.